# java data Encryption/Decryption : Encryption key to be with the tool owner not with developers

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, db2, public-key-encryption

I have created java encryption/decryption methods using good encryption algorithms and we are using both functionalities in our application .These methods are working  based on encryption key(string).

As a developer  I can see the encryption key in my java file and using that key I can do decryption.My client need to hide that encryption key from developers and key should be with tool owner.

I am using java 1.7 version,DB2 database and WebSphere application server .

How is this possible ?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the secret in runtime. This can be done either by using system properties, environment properties or just plain-old properties files. You can use libraries/framework like: [`Spring`/`Spring Boot`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) etc. But... there is no problem in writing it by yourself, it's just a call to `System.getProperty()`, [`Properties.load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment,Can you please make your answer little more clear or can you please provide any valuable documentation link for my reference